# Finding respective Taylor series of function

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

I need your help with finding the Taylor sequence of $ f(x) =\sin(x) $ at $x_0 = \pi/4 $.

I'm having problem with using the summation notation as the signs are a bit tricky
I got that:
$ T_f(x) = \frac{\sqrt2}{2} + \frac{\sqrt2}{2}x - \frac{\frac{\sqrt2}{2}x^2}{2!}  
 - \frac{\frac{\sqrt2}{2}x^3}{3!}  $

Because of the signs switching like this, I can't figure out how can I write the general summation form (i.e. with Sigma notation).
Thank you

Comment: Don't forget that it's $\left( x - \frac{\pi}{4} \right)^k$.  I would say write it as the sum of two different series that both alternate.

Comment: I understand what you say but not sure which series I should use...

Comment: Make all the odd terms one series and all the even terms another series. They will both alternate $(-1)^n$. Then the series for $\sin(x)$ will be the sum of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**

Making the problem more general: what is the Taylor expansion of $\sin(x)$ around $x=a$ ?

Let $x=y+a$ and use $$\sin(y+a)=\sin(a)\cos(y)+\cos(a) \sin(y)$$ Use the well known Taylor series of $\sin(y)$ and $\cos(y)$ around $y=0$ and when finished, replace $y$ by $(x-a)$.

Comment: That would create a series expansion for the sine, but it wouldn't be *the* Taylor series around $x_0$, wouldn't it?

Comment: No, since the series will be in terms of $y$ which is $x-a$.

Comment: Oh, I see. You're right. Then this is indeed a nice solution.

Answer (score 1):

The general formula for the Taylor Series of a function $f(x)$ around $x_0$ is $$f(x)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{f^{(n)}(x_0)}{n!}(x-x_0)^n$$

Recall $\sin(\frac{\pi}{4})=\cos(\frac{\pi}{4})=\frac{1}{\sqrt2}$ to obtain $$\sin(x)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}{n!}(x-\frac{\pi}{4})^n$$

Answer (score 0):

Notice that

$$\sin'(x)=\cos(x)=\sin\left(x+\frac\pi2\right),\\
\sin''(x)=-\sin(x)=\sin\left(x+2\frac\pi2\right),\\
\sin'''(x)=-\cos(x)=\sin\left(x+3\frac\pi2\right),\\\cdots$$

and you can write

$$\sin\left(x\right)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{\sin\left(\dfrac\pi4+k\dfrac\pi2\right)}{k!}\left(x-\dfrac\pi4\right)^k.$$